Function that returns a tuple type from array of keys
I'm trying to construction a function where you pass an object, and an array of keys (This is a simplified example to illustrate what im trying to achieve). Then return is an array that contain those keys, and has the type of a tuple. The problem that I'm struggling with is that the return type is the union of all types in the interface, not the actual value of the given key.
I tried adding the const parameter to the function but to no avail. I guess the error lies in the K parameter not infering the key granular enough..?
type User = {
    name: string,
    location: string
    age: number    
}

const fooUser: User = {
    age: 30,
    name: "Foo",
    location: "Bar",
}

const getSelected = <T extends User, const K extends readonly(keyof User)[]>(user: T, keys: K) => {
    return keys.map((key) => user[key]);
}

const [age, userName] = getSelected(fooUser, ['age', 'name'])
        //  ^? const age: string | number

// Would want the array typed as [string, number]


That's... not what a type is. The point of typing something is to be able to know what kind of data you'll get without running the code. But if you just have a keyof User, that's just a subset of strings (the ones used to key into that dictionary). Finding out what type of data you'll get by using that key in a User, depends on which key it is, and is solved by actually looking it up which doesn't happen ahead of time. Yes, for your example that could be solved statically because the input is a compile-time constant. But ordinary type systems just don't work that way.

Which is to say: I don't actually know TypeScript, but I strongly doubt the problem is solvable, and it further seems unreasonable to expect this capability. The language appears to be telling you "the type of an unknown key of User is string | number", because that's what it is: whatever key you use in a User, you'll get either a string or a number (or an error), but knowing which requires knowing the value of the key, not just its type.

I hear what you're saying but I don't fully just buy that it's not solveable yet.. We do know what keys are passed, and that should be able to be used to infer the types. I added a utility type(That errors for now, but it should show that we can achieve the effect that I'm looking for): https://tsplay.dev/wOVJ6W

@KarlKnechtel the more I think about it, the more i believe you're actually right. I guess my biggest source of confusion is probably generic constraints... I'm still building my mental model of them.

This is definitely possible assuming the list of keys is known at compile time. I’ll write a demo and show how it works when I get off mobile.

Does this approach meet your needs? If so, I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Yes!! It's exactly what i wanted :D Please if you would @jcalz

@jcalz shouldn't it be const K extends readonly (keyof T)[] instead of const K extends readonly (keyof User)[]?

I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance.  @RoboRobok It really depends on what the use case is.
